# How to disable the assist input when the home button is long pressed?

Tags: google-apps, google-search, home-button, google-assistant

I have removed Google Now in order to assign long press on home button to open another app. But recently it comes back with a different interface I'm familiar with. I guess the phone just has updated it.

However I'm unable to disable or uninstall it. In Google Play I can't find which app has just been updated. In the setting of the app there is no option to disable it.

These are some system Google apps that's under my suspicion: Google Services Framework, Google Partner Setup, Google One Time Init, Google Play Store and Google Play services. But I find no evidence to against them.

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it's actually from [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Basic-Browsing/Search-Firefox-instantly-on-your-Android-home-screen/ta-p/34579), not Google. To disable this, go to *Setting › Apps › Configure apps (the gear button) › Default Apps › Assist & voice input* and change to none:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

Try installing a launcher, like Nova. It gives you a vast amount of options for customisation of your device, including long press home.

***Hope this helps***

Comment: I'm not sure promoting "pirating" paid apps on here is a good idea, certainly not moral.

Comment: sorry, will edit accordingly, went for maximum benefit of users here @JonnyWright

Comment: I'm actually in a non-stock launcher (Apex). I also have root and Xposed, but this still happens